# How to create zip file from a large folder using Codeigniter and PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip, backup

I'm trying to create zip file from a large folder which size almost 2GB. My code is working well on the localhost but it's not working on the server(Cpanel). In server, it's creating a zip file which size is only 103 MB out of 2GB. According to my strategy, first of all, I'm creating a backup folder recursively named "system_backup". And the backup folder is creating well without any problem. The next is, to create the zip file of 'system_backup' folder by calling the function ZipData and stored it to another folder. In this time, it's not creating the zip file properly.

After that, the function ***rrmdir*** will be called. And it will delete the 'system_backup' folder recursively. And the deletion is not working properly as well. And, in localhost, it works well.

Then, when I'm trying to download the created zip file by the function ***download_file***, it also not download properly. It's downloaded as a broken zip file. And, in localhost, it also works well.

I have already checked the read and write permission of folders and files.

The code is given below:-

```
public function backup_app(){
    //Backup System
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->recurse_copy(FCPATH,'system_backup');

    $backup_name = 'Customs-system-backup-on_'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
    $path   = FCPATH.'system_backup';
    $destination = FCPATH.'bdCustomsBackup/'.$backup_name;
    $this->zipData($path, $destination);

    //Delete directory
    $this->rrmdir($path);

    $message = "Application Backup on ".date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
    $this->submit_log($message);

    echo 1;
}

function zipData($source, $destination) {
    if (extension_loaded('zip')) {
        if (file_exists($source)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
                $source = realpath($source);
                if (is_dir($source)) {
                    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source);
                    // skip dot files while iterating 
                    $iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                    $counter = 1;
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        $file = realpath($file);
                        if (is_dir($file)) {
                            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', 'system_backup/', $file . '/'));
                        } else if (is_file($file)) {                                
                            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', 'system_backup/', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (is_file($source)) {
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                }
            }
            return $zip->close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src);
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' ) && ( $file != $dst ) && ( $file != "bdCustomsBackup" )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                $this->recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}

public function rrmdir($src) {
    $dir = opendir($src);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            $full = $src . '/' . $file;
            if ( is_dir($full) ) {
                $this->rrmdir($full);
            }
            else {
                unlink($full);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    rmdir($src);
}

public function download_file($file){
    $message = "Download ".$file." on ".date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
    $this->submit_log($message);

    $path = FCPATH.'bdCustomsBackup/'.$file;

    $this->load->helper('download_helper');
    force_download($file, $path);
}
```

Here is the custom ***download_helper***:-

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('force_download'))
{
    function force_download($filename = '', $file = '')
    {
        if ($filename == '' OR $file == '')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Try to determine if the filename includes a file extension.
        // We need it in order to set the MIME type
        if (FALSE === strpos($filename, '.'))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Grab the file extension
        $x = explode('.', $filename);
        $extension = end($x);

        // Load the mime types
        @include(APPPATH.'config/mimes'.EXT);

        // Set a default mime if we can't find it
        if ( ! isset($mimes[$extension]))
        {
            $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
        }
        else
        {
            $mime = (is_array($mimes[$extension])) ? $mimes[$extension][0] : $mimes[$extension];
        }

        // Generate the server headers
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE") !== FALSE)
        {
            header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Pragma: public');
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
        }
        else
        {
            header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
        }

        readfile_chunked($file);
        die;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('readfile_chunked'))
{
    function readfile_chunked($file, $retbytes=TRUE)
    {
       $chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024);
       $buffer = '';
       $cnt =0;

       $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
       if ($handle === FALSE)
       {
           return FALSE;
       }

       while (!feof($handle))
       {
           $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
           echo $buffer;
           ob_flush();
           flush();

           if ($retbytes)
           {
               $cnt += strlen($buffer);
           }
       }

       $status = fclose($handle);

       if ($retbytes AND $status)
       {
           return $cnt;
       }

       return $status;
    }
}

/* End of file download_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/download_helper.php */
```

Comment: Is there anything in PHP error log file related to issue?

Comment: [02-Apr-2018 00:18:53 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 138674176) (tried to allocate 215251045 bytes) in /home/sandboxeasyhost/public_html/bdCustoms/application/controllers/backup_process.php on line 86.

 But I'm using ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` means all allowed server resources. Seems provider gives you 128MB for used package.

Comment: Hello Shoukhin i am having a similar issue as we speak. Did you manage to find a solution to this issue? If so can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

**The below code is using PHP:**

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open('test_new.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
        {
            // Add files to the zip file
            $zip->addFile('test.txt');
            $zip->addFile('test.pdf');

            // Add random.txt file to zip and rename it to newfile.txt
            $zip->addFile('random.txt', 'newfile.txt');

            // Add a file new.txt file to zip using the text specified
            $zip->addFromString('new.txt', 'text to be added to the new.txt file');

            // All files are added, so close the zip file.
            $zip->close();
        }
```

**Explanation of code**

Line 1 creates an object of the ZipArchive class

Line 2 opens a file with filename as test_new.zip so that we can add files to it. The flag ZipArchive::CREATE specifies that we want to create a new zip file

Lines 5 & 6 are used to add files to the zip file

Line 9 is used to add a file with name random.txt to the zip file and rename it in the zipfile as newfile.txt

Line 12 is used to add a new file new.txt with contents of the file as ‘text to be added to the new.txt file’

Line 15 closes and saves the changes to the zip file

Note: Sometimes there can be issues when using relative paths for files. If there are any issues using paths then we can also use absolute paths for files

**Overwrite an existing zip file**

If you want to overwrite an existing zip file then we can use code similar to following. The flag ZipArchive::OVERWRITE overwrites the existing zip file.

```
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open('test_overwrite.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE)
            {
                // Add file to the zip file
                $zip->addFile('test.txt');
                $zip->addFile('test.pdf');

                // All files are added, so close the zip file.
                $zip->close();
            }
```

**Explanation of code**

This code will create a file test_overwrite.zip if it already exists the file will be overwritten with this new file

**Create a new zip file and add files to be inside a folder**

```
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open('test_folder.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
            {
                // Add files to the zip file inside demo_folder
                $zip->addFile('text.txt', 'demo_folder/test.txt');
                $zip->addFile('test.pdf', 'demo_folder/test.pdf');

                // Add random.txt file to zip and rename it to newfile.txt and store in demo_folder
                $zip->addFile('random.txt', 'demo_folder/newfile.txt');

                // Add a file demo_folder/new.txt file to zip using the text specified
                $zip->addFromString('demo_folder/new.txt', 'text to be added to the new.txt file');

                // All files are added, so close the zip file.
                $zip->close();
            }
```

**Explanation of code**

The above code will add different files inside the zip file to be inside a folder demo_folder

The 2nd parameter to addfile function can be used to store the file in a new folder

The 1st parameter in the addFromString function can be used to store the file in a new folder

**Create a new zip file and move the files to be in different folders**

```
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open('test_folder_change.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
            {
                // Add files to the zip file
                $zip->addFile('text.txt', 'demo_folder/test.txt');
                $zip->addFile('test.pdf', 'demo_folder1/test.pdf');

                // All files are added, so close the zip file.
                $zip->close();
            }
```

**Explanation of code**

We store the file test.txt into demo_folder and test.pdf into demo_folder1

**Create a zip file with all files from a directory**

```
                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                if ($zip->open('test_dir.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE)
                {
                    if ($handle = opendir('demo_folder'))
                    {
                        // Add all files inside the directory
                        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
                        {
                            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !is_dir('demo_folder/' . $entry))
                            {
                                $zip->addFile('demo_folder/' . $entry);
                            }
                        }
                        closedir($handle);
                    }

                    $zip->close();
                }
```

**Explanation of code**

Lines 5-16 opens a directory and creates a zip file with all files within that directory

Line 5 opens the directory

Line 7 gets the name of each file in the dir

Line 9 skips the “.” and “..” and any other directories

Line 11 adds the file into the zip file

Line 14 closes the directory

Line 17 closes the zip file